# how to match a particular string with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match following pattern `India` in the string `"$str=Sri Lanka Under-19s 235/5 * v India Under-19s 503/7 "`. It should return false because instead of `India`, `India Under-19s` is present? If only `India` is present without under 19 how to do this with regex. Please help.

It should match only if `india` is present and should fail if `india under-19` is present.

I have written following code for this but it is always matching-

```
$str="Sri Lanka Under-19s 235/5 * v India Under-19s 503/7";
$team="#India\s(?!("Under-19s"))#";
preg_match($team,$str,$matches);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you are asking:

```
<?php

 $str="Sri Lanka Under-19s 235/5 * v India Under-19s 503/7";
 $team="/India\s(?!Under-19s)/";
 preg_match($team,$str,$matches);

 exit;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$text = "Sri Lanka Under-19s 235/5 * v India Under-19s 503/7";

$check = explode(" ", strstr($text, "India"));
if( $check[1] == "Under-19s" ){
    // If is in text
}else{
    // If not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching the lack of a string in a regexp is a bit ugly. This is a little clearer:

```
$india_regexp = '/india/i';
$under19_regexp = '/under-19s/i';
$match = preg_match(india_regexp, $str) && ! preg_match(under19_regexp, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a single white space between  India and Under-19s regular expression to check for that would be.

```
/India\s(?!Under)/
```

Put all together in code

```
$string = "Sri Lanka Under-19s 235/5 * v India  Under-19s 503/7";
$pattern="/India\s(?!Under)/";
preg_match($pattern,$string,$match);
  if(count($match)==0){
       //What we need
  }else{
       //Under-19 is present
  }
```